# How to implement timeout for getline()?

Tags: c++, gcc, centos

I want to read a string from command line through `getline()` in c++.

For that I want to add a timer of `5` sec. If no string read, then the program will terminate.

How can I do this?

Comment: @RandyHoward : I don't think this is an exact duplicate. `getline()` is much simpler to use, and know how to add a counter to it would be useful to those who are new. This question should remain legitimate.

Comment: @kassak : Nope, still not an exact duplicate, the answers show that, I think. Either way, I think this is a useful question, because `getline()` is used quite a lot, and knowing how to use it well would be good for future readers. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would say the question is ok (after edit), since it has [quite good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15524177/476681)

Comment: @BЈовић You would be wrong.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac no, this is not about using `getline` "well"; quite the opposite. If you need this kind of functionality, hacking it into getline is silly, because it will be a messy brittle hack. There are better ways of doing this, and they involve not using getline.

Comment: many ways..?? good..
what are the ways you have to solve this problem ?? - R. Martinho Fernandes

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes : Why don't you elaborate on that, since you seem to know it quite well.

Comment: There is no standard-based solution to this, but there are libraries that can be used to do it, like ncurses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
/* Wait 5 seconds. */
alarm(5);

/* getline */

/* Cancel alarm. */
alarm(0);
```

Alternatively you could use `setitimer`.

---

As *R. Martinho Fernandes* requested:

The function `alarm` arranges for the current process to receive a SIGALRM in 5 seconds from its call. The default action for a `SIGALRM` si to terminate the process abnormally. Calling `alarm(0)` disables the timer.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to close and reopen stdin or something to get past the getline statement...?

Comment: and at last i m getting output as "Alarm clock". How to suppress that one ??? thanks @cnicutar

Comment: If this answered your original question, it'll work better to accept this answer, and ask a new question about the "Alarm clock" output showing your code.

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Good call, edited.

Comment: @cnicutar: I think it'd be good to add that `alarm` is POSIX-specific.

Comment: with out using "alarm(0)"
if i want to continue with some other task, then how to use..?? 
thanks .. -cnicutar

Comment: @user2164410 I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: after 5 seconds alarm(0) is executing and the program terminating.
But, now after 5 sec if i want to do some other task. then ?? -cnicutar

Comment: `alarm(0)` should _disable_ the timer.

Answer (score 8):

ok, wait for `5` sec, and `terminate` if there was no input:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> flag = false;
    std::thread([&]
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

        if (!flag)
            std::terminate();
    }).detach();

    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    flag = true;
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Comment: +1 for standard solution, hehe

Comment: with out using threads pllzzz...

Comment: @user2164410 - why not - it's the usual way of handling such requirements.  It would just as easy to allow the signaling of a line entry before the 5 seconds is up, rather than waiting until the end of the interval.

Comment: -Martin James
that's okay.. But, now what i want is.. if i am not reading any string after 5 sec i don't want to exit from program, i needs to call another function and come back to the getline(). (Looping).
thanks

Comment: -Abyx
it is giving many compile time errors..
compile the code once ..

and if possible don't include any threads.
thanks

Comment: I basically did this without the knowledge that the thread would continue taking input and got flamed for hoping it could work :p