# std::getline in std::async does not terminate after timeout

Tags: c++

Duplicate of [Is it possible to set timeout for std::cin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053175)

Comment: In short you cannot with `cin`. Dealing with input in a less abstract way than "a byte stream" requires using other tools. In posix world, you would use `select` or a similar mechanism, in windows world GetMessage or something similar.

Comment: [just use alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524122/how-to-implement-timeout-for-getline)

Comment: `alarm` is not portable (windows, looking at you), and there is no guarantee it will actually interrupt cin (though it does in all platforms implementing it that I know of).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set timeout for std::cin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053175/is-it-possible-to-set-timeout-for-stdcin)

Comment: @spectras Do you know why it is not possible? What is the underlying reason?

Comment: Your program only finishes once all threads are done. So your main thread completes at timeout. Then the program waits for your cin thread to complete before finishing.